# Public Xcode Asset Catalog Extensions from Module

Tags: swift, xcode, asset-catalog

I've enabled "Generate Swift Asset Symbol Extensions" in my UI framework / module so my Asset Catalog images and colours are accessible from `UIColor.myColor` and `UIImage.myImage` etc, but I can't access these from the main App target as they are internal, and not public.

How can I make these extensions available on the app target? Is there another configuration property that sets the access level?